# Raiserror in procedure (SQL Server 2005) is not caught in update process in client side(c#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, raiserror

I am using stored procedure with RAISERROR. The error raised by the SP is not caught by the try catch statement in c#.Net. I'm using SqlDataSource for SQL connection and SqlDataSource_Updating event to update the data.

SQL Code:

```
DECLARE @count int
@count=0
   if(@count = 0)
   begin
   RAISERROR('Updation failed. record already exists', 16, 1) 
  end
```

c# Code:

```
protected void sqlDataSource_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    // Assigns the update command parameter
    e.Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fag", Flg));
    e.Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date", DateTime.Now));

  }
  //catch (SqlException ex)
  //{


  //}
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // If so, checks the Exception message
    if (ex.Message == "Updation failed. record Not exists")
    {
        // Display the details of the exception to the user
        lblMessage.Text = " record already exists";
    }

    // Writes the error in log file
    WriteErrorLog(ex.Message , "sqlDataSource_Updating");
  }
}
```

SQLDataSource:

```
                SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [Name], [Flg] FROM [Master] ORDER BY Name "  

                InsertCommand="exec [Master_Insert] @ID, @Name, @Flg, @createdDate, @createdBy, @updatedDate, @updatedBy"

                UpdateCommand="exec [Master_Update] @ID, @Name, @Flg, @updatedDate, @updatedBy"

                 DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM Master WHERE ID = @ID" 
                            oninserted="sqlDataSource_Inserted" 
                            oninserting="sqlDataSource_Inserting" 
                            onupdated="sqlDataSource_Updated" 
                            onupdating="sqlDataSource_Updating"> 
                </asp:sqldatasource>
```

Regards
Geetha

Comment: Could you post more of the throwing stored procedure, and the try/catch block in C# that's supposed to catch it?

Comment: Where do you *execute* the proc?

Comment: You have commented out "SqlException" for "Exception".  "SqlException" should catch the error.  Is this not working for "SqlException" as well?

Comment: Yes SQLException is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You for all your replies.

By using a e.Exception in sqlDataSource_Updated my problem got solved.

```
protected void sqlDataSource_Updated(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)

{

       if (e.Exception != null)
            {

                // If so, checks the Exception message

                if (e.Exception.Message == "record already exists")

                {

                }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Updating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updating.aspx) event is used to customize the SqlCommand being executed, but it does not execute the command. The try/catch block must wrap the actual place where the command is executed, not the customization callback.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed right away is that the error message that your stored procedure is raising "Updation failed. **record already exists**" does not match the text string, "Updation failed. **record Not exists**", that you are checking in your try/catch block.